# Create a sort of view tab with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

is there a way to mirror data from one tab in Excel to another tab(view) if it meets certain conditions(colour), and stop doing so as soon as the condition gets changed(colour gets changed in view)? Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out any way to do it with formulas only.

The reason I need this is that we will have a shared Excel file. New data will get added every week into the main data tab. The data will then be reviewed by another party, data will be added, and the colour will be changed, playing the ball back to us. So there should be two additional sheets.

1. No colour/white: All rows without colour can be seen in View1. Party1 knows that they need to give input. When they did so, they change the colour in View1 to orange and the rows can now be seen in View2
2. Orange: All orange rows can be seen here so it is clear that they need further processing. When Party2 processed the records, they change the colour to green. The data should not be visible in any View, but should go green in the main Data tab.

Unfortunately I am very green when it comes to VBA, so any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

[The 3 tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAuez.png)

Comment: will the data be modified in the view tab? or is everything done in the main tab?

Comment: it is of course possible with vba. But if you only Need to filter it, you can filter by Color -> https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/912-excel-filter-by-cell-color.html

Comment: Hi,

thank you for coming back to me. Indeed, data in the view tab should be modified.New data will be added in a certain column, and the colour will be changed .

So as soon as the colour was in the view, it should disappear from the view and appear in the other view. Except it goes green, then it should not be in any view, but shoud appear green in the MainDataTab.